# How to computer sending/receiving process in MPI_Allreduce

Tags: mpi

In `MPI_Allreduce()` each step you send a number of bytes to another process. You also receive a number of bytes from the same process you're sending to.

Is there an straightforward way to compute these partner processes? For example:

In step 0: process 0-1, 2-3, ...
In step 1: process 0-2, 1-3, ...
In step 2: process 0-4, ...

Comment: What do you means? Do you want to understand how to reimplement the algorithm with `MPI_Send()` and `MPI_Recv()`? Do you want a way of printing what is happening internally within your MPI library? Something else?

Comment: Reimplementing MPI_Allreduce. In that algorithm I need to know a destination and a source in MPI_Send or MPI_Receive. The question is about  computing those.

Comment: OK but you do understand that your own reimplementation is likely to have nothing to do with what is actually done inside your MPI library, right? So this can only be for the sake of doing it, not for demonstrating anything...

Comment: I would suggest implementing `MPI_Allreduce` as a combination of `MPI_Reduce` and `MPI_Bcast`. Those are trivial to implement naively with `MPI_Send` / `MPI_Recv`. If you must reimplement it optimized & efficiently then there should be plenty of papers and open source code to learn from.

Comment: Just to exemplify my previous remark, have a look at [this excellent blog post](http://hiliev.eu/en/posts/mpi-trace-art.html) from @HristoIliev . It is about `MPI_Bcast()`, not `MPI_Allreduce()` but it already shows quite well how diverse and complex internal implementations can be.

Comment: Yeah. It's for demonstration/educational purposes.

Comment: There you go - [all the different ways](https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/blob/v1.10/ompi/mca/coll/tuned/coll_tuned_allreduce.c) reduce-to-all is implemented in Open MPI 1.10. The logic that selects one of those in each particular call to `MPI_Allreduce` is [here](https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/blob/v1.10/ompi/mca/coll/tuned/coll_tuned_decision_fixed.c#L35).